# Is the color problem with my Facetime camera on a new Macbook Air a hardware or software problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, color, webcam

I've brought a Macbook Air few months ago. I didn't get to test its camera when I brought it. I'd gotten too busy with works and today was my first time running the application Facetime to test my camera.

I was really taken aback.

Here is a photo I captured with Photo Booth.

[image: there is something wrong with my camera or the]

The layer facing top is supposed to be red, but it looks green (and green stuff looks red). The camera also seems to have a hard time capturing photons.

(my room is pretty bright yet it looks so dim in the picture)

Is this a driver problem or a hardware problem?

*P.S. I've recently re-installed my Mac OSX system using the built-in function that downloads everything from Apple.*

Comment: I would say send it back to Apple for warranty claim.

Comment: I'd agree.  Switching colors makes me wonder if a cable is installed backwards.